# retrieving every attribute of every column from every row of a table mysql java

Tags: mysql, jdbc

So far I know that it's possible to select the nth row from a table using the following code 
  `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column_name LIMIT n-1,1 ;` 
 In the following code I am trying to retrieve every attribute of every column from every row of a table named responsable which has the following columns :id,name,surname,mail,password. id is an integer while the other columns' type is string

```
java.sql.Connection connection = null;
int rowCount;
try {connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name","root","");
      Statement stmt = null;
      ResultSet result = null;
      ResultSet rs = null;
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM responsable");
      rowCount = rs.getInt(1);
      if(rowCount!=0)
       {
        for(int i=0;i<rowCount;i++)
         {result= stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM responsable ORDER BY id LIMIT"+i+",1");
          System.out.put(result.getInt(1));
          System.out.put(result.getString(2));
          System.out.put(result.getString(3));
          System.out.put(result.getString(4));
          System.out.put(result.getString(5));}
       }
}catch (Exception ex) {
out.println("Unable to connect to database");
}
```

I am trying to execute this code but I am getting no result.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM responsable might be returning 0 rows.

Comment: i am sure that the table is not empty

Comment: Why don't you see what's in rowCount before you drop into your conditional?  If it's 0 then your table isn't spelled right or something else.  Your entire output is based off 1 variable, you really need to figure out what it's being set to.

Comment: The problem is from `result= stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM responsable ORDER BY id LIMIT"+i+",1");` it is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stmt` variable is null.  You need to create the statement first.

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
```

Also, you need to call next() to retrieve the next row from your resultset.
E.g.

```
if (rs.next()) {
    rowCount = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

....

```
if (result.next()) {
    System.out.put(result.getInt(1));
    System.out.put(result.getString(2));
    System.out.put(result.getString(3));
    System.out.put(result.getString(4));
    System.out.put(result.getString(5));
}
```